# Python pygame crashing, fixes don't seem to work

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I'm trying to make a platformer, and in the code below I'm trying to move one image ('bird.png') around on the background. However, every time I try to launch pygame it crashes without even loading any of the images. I checked out the other pages and it still didn't fix the problem. There are probably a few mistakes in the code, but I can't check if it's working properly because as I said, pygame keeps crashing. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

PS. Sorry if it's a bit messy, and for the french words in the code :)

```
import pygame 
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

TE=[] 

def perso(X):
    X = [0,448]
    while X != [640,0]:
         w=int(input("Déplacement: "))
#Right#
         if w==0:
              if X[1] == 608:
                   print("You can't leave the map")
              else:    
                   X[1] +=  32
                   print(X)     
#Left#
         elif w==1:
              if X[1] == 0:
                   print("You can't leave the map")
              else:
                   X[1] -= 32
                   print(X)     
#Down#  
         elif w==2:
              if X[0] == 456:
                   print("You can't leave the map")
              else:
                   X[0] += 24
                   print(X)     
#Up#
         elif w==3:
              if X[0] == 0:
                   print("You can't leave the map")
              else:
                   X[0] -= 24
                   print(X)
         else:
              print("non valable")
    print("Bravo!")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((680, 488)) background_image = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/Scripts/Images & Sounds/background(680x480).jpg").convert()
screen.blit(background_image,[0,0])

character = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/Scripts/Images & Sounds/bird(40x40).png").convert()
screen.blit(character, (X[0],X[1]))

perso(TE)


flag
```

I run the code and when the pygame window opens, it's black and after a few seconds I get the 'not responding' message (for the pygame window). However, the `w=int(input("Déplacement: "))` part seems to work as it asks for an input. Maybe it's something to do with the images?

Comment: What do you mean by crashing - you need to give the specific exception code you are experiencing

Comment: I run the code and when the pygame window opens, it's black and after a few seconds I get the 'not responding' message (for the pygame window). However, the "w=int(input("Déplacement: "))" part seems to work as it asks for an input. Maybe it's something to do with the images?

Comment: You have a **while** loop with a potentially unfulfilled condition. Id suspect that.  Add **while not 640 stuff and cntr <100**.  Then have **cntr +=1** in body and **cntr = 0 ** before loop.

Comment: Id also put a print right before deplacement prompt. And get rid of accent, just in case its bumming about non-English chars.

Comment: Also you could try copying your file to c:\temp\nofunnychars.png and refer to it that way, wo weird '/' on windows tricks

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest game loops consists of an "update" sequence and a "render" sequence that are called each time through the loop. Both of these sequences should take very little time to complete (the faster the better). It could be that Python's built in `input` function is stopping the "update" sequence and causing the game to crash because it can't continue the loop.

The easiest way to solve this would be to just use Pygame's built-in key input methods. It's also a good idea to break out the "render" and "update" sequences to help distinguish between the game logic and the rendering of images.

```
import pygame 
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((680, 488)) 
background_image = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/Scripts/Images & Sounds/background(680x480).jpg").convert()
character = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/Scripts/Images & Sounds/bird(40x40).png").convert()

def move(X):
    keys = pygame.get_pressed()
    #Right#
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] != 0:
        if X[1] == 608:
             print("You can't leave the map")
        else:    
             X[1] +=  32
             print(X)     
    #Left#
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] != 0:
        if X[1] == 0:
             print("You can't leave the map")
        else:
             X[1] -= 32
             print(X)     
    #Down#  
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] != 0:
        if X[0] == 456:
             print("You can't leave the map")
        else:
             X[0] += 24
             print(X)     
    #Up#
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] != 0:
        if X[0] == 0:
             print("You can't leave the map")
        else:
             X[0] -= 24
             print(X)
    else:
        print("non valable")

    return X


def draw(X):
    screen.blit(background_image,[0,0])
    screen.blit(character, (X[0],X[1]))

Running = True
X = [0,448]
while Running:

    # Updated and draw
    X = move(X)
    draw(X)

    # Allow for the user to exit the game
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type==QUIT:
            Running = False
            exit()

    # End the game if
    if X == [640, 0]:
        Running = False
        exit()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a bunch. However, i do have some questions about your code (i'm quite new to python). There seems to be an error with "X = move(X)" as it says X is not defined. How do I fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I was not able to test the code above so I knew there would be some errors if it was used verbatim. You get an error there because X hasn't been initialized before you used it in the move function. Add `X = [0,448]` above the while loop and that error should disappear.